# How to use a 'no-cors' fetched ressource cached by a service worker?

Tags: javascript

I am still learning webdev and was reading about CORS this morning. I was curious to know if it is possible to use a resource fetched with no-cors mode. I did read it was possible with service workers, I am able to cache the resource but I have no idea how to use it.

I tried in my main script:

```
window.caches.open( 'resources' )
    .then( cache => {
      cache.match('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
      .then( r => {
        console.log('found in cache: ', r)
        })
      })
```

But r is the fetched Response.type opaque. Is it possible to use it in my main script ?

[Chrome console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I89x.png)